# How to test if axios instance is called?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test if the axios instance "myApi" is being called

function code

```
const myApi = axios.create({
  baseURL
})

async function auth () {
    const request = await myApi.post('/authorization', {
      email,
      password
    })
    return request
}
```

how can I access the "myApi" instance in the test?

Comment: What kind of "test" are you writing? You could always `export const myApi` and import it from the test file

Comment: @Livebughelp-www.dialect.so I'm trying to write a test like this: expect(myApi.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))

Comment: Then, you should export `myApi` from the source file by writing `export const myApi = axios.create({ baseURL })` and then import it in the test file.

Comment: I tried to do it but received a error message:
 Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Comment: I think you need to use the `spyOn` function: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname `const spy = jest.spyOn(myApi, 'post'); expect(spy.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))`